Can we get small answers in azure ai search index and demo application?
I have a azure ai search service created as cente***dataservice1. In this search service, I have taken basic tier package. There are multiple things that I have done while creating index. First, I have created skillset as text-split-skillset and made index using azure blob storage where pdf, excel and other format multiple documents are stored. The fields that I took are
content: The full text content of the document.
metadata_storage_path: The storage path or URL where the document is stored.
metadata_author: The author of the document.
metadata_title: The title of the document.
metadata_creation_date: The creation date of the document.
language: The language of the document.
split_text: The chunks of text resulting from the text-split-skill.
merged_content: Possibly a concatenated or aggregated version of the content.
keywords: Keywords extracted from the document for search optimization.
summary: A summary of the document.
section_titles: Titles of sections within the document.
metadata_filetype: The type of file (e.g., PDF, DOCX, etc.).
I have also created semantic configuration in index as
docs-test where in Title fields, I took metadata_title field.
In Content fields, I took content and merged_content fields.
In Keywords field, I took keywords field.
When I asking question in search explorer in index, then answer is very long that I am getting and also not very accurate. It's like
Question is what are different percentages of GHG emmisions?
{
"@search.score": 1.5097852,
"content": "\nImpact Report\n2019\n\n1\n\n\n\nIntroduction 03\n\nLifecycle Analysis of Tesla Vehicles versus Average ICE\n\nBattery Recycling\n\nNOx, Particulates and Other Pollutants\n\nWater Used per Vehicle Manufactured\n\nEmissions Credits\n\nNet Energy Impact of Our Products\nOur Environmental, Health, and Safety Strategy\n\nSafety Improvements\n\nCase Study: Ergonomics and Model Y Design\n\nRewarding the Individual\n\nCulture of Diversity and Inclusion\n\nWorkforce Development\n\nCommunity Engagement\n\nEmployee Mobility and Transportation Programs\n\nCorporate Governance\n\nPrice Equivalency\n\nPrimary Driver\n\nLong Distance Travel\n\nActive Safety \n\nPassive Safety\n\nTesla Safety Awards\n\nFire Safety \n\nCyber Security\n\nDisaster Relief\n\nResilience of the Grid\n\nMegapack\n\nSolar Roof\n\nEnvironmental Impact  06\n\nProduct Impact  20\n\nResponsible Material Sourcing\n\nCobalt Sourcing\n\nSupply Chain 33\n\nPeople and Culture  37\n\nAppendix   52\n\nMission and Tesla Ecosystem  04\n\n\n\nThe very purpose of Tesla’s existence is to accelerate the world’s transition to \nsustainable energy. In furtherance of this mission, we are excited to publish \nour second annual Impact Report. Transparency and disclosure are important \nfor our customers, employees, and shareholders, which is why we have \nexpanded the Impact Report’s content this year.\n\nWhile many environmental reports focus on emissions generated by the \nmanufacturing phase of products and future goals for energy consumption, \nwe highlight the totality of the environmental impact of our products today. \nAfter all, the vast majority of emissions generated by vehicles today occur in \nthe product-use phase—that is, when consumers are driving their vehicles. We \nbelieve that providing information on both sides of the manufacturing and \nconsumer-use equation provides a clearer picture of the environmental impact \nof Tesla products, and we have done so this year largely through a lifecycle \nanalysis detailed in this report.\n\nIntroduction Tesla aims to continue to increase the proportion of renewable energy usage \nat our factories in an effort to minimize the carbon footprint for every mile \ntraveled by our products and their components in our supply chain. All of the \nfactories that we built from the ground-up, such as Gigafactory Nevada and \nGigafactory Shanghai, and our forthcoming Gigafactories in Berlin and North \nAmerica, are designed from the beginning to use energy from renewable \nsources.\n\nMaking a significant and lasting impact on environmental sustainability is \ndifficult to achieve without securing financial sustainability for the long term. \nWe generated positive Free Cash Flow (operating cash flow less capex) of \nmore than $1 billion for the first time in 2019. We believe the notion that a \nsustainable future is not economically feasible is no longer valid.\n\n\n\n4\n\nClimate change is reaching alarming levels in large part due to emissions from burning \nfossil fuels for transportation and electricity generation. In 2016, carbon dioxide (CO2) \nconcentration levels in the atmosphere exceeded the 400 parts per million threshold on \na sustained basis - a level that climate scientists believe will have a catastrophic impact \non the environment. Worse, annual global CO2 emissions continue to increase and have \napproximately doubled over the past 50 years to over 43 gigatons in 2019. The world’s \ncurrent path is unwise and unsustainable.\n\nThe world cannot reduce CO2 emissions without addressing both energy generation \nand consumption. And the world cannot address its energy habits without first directly \nreducing emissions in the transportation and energy sectors. We are focused on \ncreating a complete energy and transportation ecosystem from solar generation and \nenergy storage to all-electric vehicles that produce zero tailpipe emissions.\n\nSince the onset of shelter-in-place orders and travel restrictions due to COVID-19, we \nhave seen dramatic increases in air quality across the planet, as well as projections for \nCO2 emissions to drop in excess of 4% in 2020 compared to pre-COVID-19 levels, \naccording to researchers. Because these improvements in air quality and reductions in \nCO2 are a result of a global economic disruption and not due to systemic changes in \nhow we produce and consume energy, they are not expected to be sustained absent \nintervention. However, these changes have shown us the positive impacts of reduced \npollution in a very short period of time. At Tesla, we believe that we all have an \nunprecedented opportunity to learn from this disruption and accelerate the deployment \nof clean energy solutions as part of a recovery for all economies throughout the world, \nand we will actively continue to advocate for the realization of these long-term \nchanges.\n\nAccording to the Global Carbon project, when fully tallied, total carbon emissions from \n2019 are expected to hit another record high of over 43 gigatons for the year. Energy use \nthrough electricity and heat production (31%) and transportation (16%) are significant \ndrivers of these GHG emissions.\n\nGlobal Greenhouse Gas (GHG) Emissions by \nEconomic Sector\n\nElectricity & Heat Production*\nAgriculture, Forestry & Other Land Use\nIndustry\nTransportation*\nOther Energy\nBuildings\n\n31%\n20%\n18%\n16%\n9%\n6%\n\n*Tesla-related sectors. Source: World Resources Institute\n\nMission & Tesla Ecosystem\n\n\n",
"metadata_storage_path": "aHR0cHM6Ly9yYWdhcHAxLmJsb2IuY29yZS53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9yYWcvMjAxOS10ZXNsYS1pbXBhY3QtcmVwb3J0LXNob3J0LnBkZg2",
"metadata_author": null,
"metadata_title": null,
"metadata_creation_date": null,
"language": null,
"split_text": [],
"merged_content": null,
"keywords": null,
"summary": null,
"section_titles": null,
"metadata_file_type": null
}
I want answer in such a way like
Question asked: what are different percentages of GHG emmisions?
Answer: There are different percent of emmisions like 31% of pollution by cars, 20% percent of pollution by factories etc.
Just a small answer of 2 lines maximum.
Below, answer there should be reference : ( small paragraph displayed from where it took information)
Is it possible to do in such a way. if yes, please help me. If index fields need to be changes, please let me know.
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Azure AI Search will not do the summarization for you. What you will need to do is take this response from Azure AI Search and feed it along with the question to Azure Open AI and ask it to summarize.

As @Gaurav Mantri said you need to integrate you ai search with azure open ai where you can ask the prompt for you content and get the result.
You follow below steps for it.
Create an azure open ai resource and deploy the model that is deployed in a supported region and with a supported model.
Next, follow steps as shown in the below image.

Next, select Azure Ai search as data source and choose the index you created.
Also, you check mark Custom field mapping so that you can add the field as required.

In the next step you add content and merged_content fields in custom field mapping content option so that your query is also searched in this fields.
After finishing the connection know you are able to ask the question you want.
Here, is the documentation for bringing your own data to azure open ai

I have one more question that I deployed a web application the way you mentioned but in order to make it for production level, can I upload pdf in frontend and ask questions and get answers or once web application is deployed, only questions we can ask from uploaded documents on which index was created?

You can do both. if you going to upload the pdf, then upload it in the blob storage where you made that as data source in your index. Based on the changes the indexer will be re-run and new documents are referenced to azure openai.
